# Crash in Android Native while changing to new Activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, openfeint, cocos2d-x

My application is unable to open OpenFeint dashboard methods. The implementation of the native c++ libraries uses cocos2d-x as a graphic library, but it has a handler and a wrapper to allow the use of OpenFeint functions. **OpenFeint initialization and non-activity methods work correctly.**

When UI dashboard functions such as openLaderBoards or openAchievements are called either from a Jni call or in the Java onCreate initialization, the application crashes.

EDIT: I have tested and it happens to any Activity change I try, even my own new classes.

EDIT2: I have a +100 bounty in a similar question, anyone who comes up with the answer gets it.

**Code**

Activity:

```
public class App extends Cocos2dxActivity{
private Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView mGLView;

OpenFeintX m_kOpenFeintX;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // get the packageName,it's used to set the resource path
    String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();
    super.setPackageName(packageName);

    InternetConnection.setM_kActivity(this);

    m_kOpenFeintX = new OpenFeintX( this);      

    setContentView(R.layout.applayout);
    mGLView = (Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.game_gl_surfaceview);
    mGLView.setTextField((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textField));                  

// Testspace for new Activities, OpenFeint or self-made
//
// Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
// startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
// Dashboard.open();


// Cocos2d-x scene opens after this

}

 static {
     System.loadLibrary("TestProject");
     // Native library loaded for cocos2d-x
 }
```

Wrapper:

```
public class OpenFeintX {

private static OpenFeintXHandler ms_kOpenFeintHandler;

public OpenFeintX(Activity kActivity) {
    initializeOpenFeint("TestApp", "derp",
            "hurr", "6546516516541",
            kActivity, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    ms_kOpenFeintHandler = new OpenFeintXHandler();

}

public static void openLeaderBoards() {     
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = OpenFeintXHandler.SHOW_LEADERBOARDS;
    ms_kOpenFeintHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

Handler openDashboard function:

```
private void openLeaderBoards() {
    System.out.println("Opening Dashboard");
    Dashboard.openLeaderboards();
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        

    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.IntroFlow"
              android:label=".IntroFlow"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow" />
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.api.ui.Dashboard"
              android:label=".Dashboard"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.Settings"
              android:label=".Settings"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>
    <activity android:name="com.openfeint.internal.ui.NativeBrowser"
              android:label=".NativeBrowser"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:theme="@style/OFNestedWindow"/>
</application>
```

Stacktrace (won't indent in SO):

http://pastebin.com/jsmSbgw4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was easy but complex. When the app changes to a new activity, the nativeOnPause method from cocos2d-x MessageJNI is called. This method is supposed to call a CCApplication::sharedApplication(), but one of my classes had previously called the CCApplication destructor, which cleared the shared singleton to null.

Even though the answer is easy to fix and project specific, I am going to give some advice on what made me find it. Keep in mind that all my tools are windows and cygwin.

**First, make Eclipse do the ndk-builds for you on clean.**

Rightclick your Project-> Properties -> C/C++ Build. Builder Settings tab, Command

```
  C:\NVPACK\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "cd /cygdrive/path/to/project && ./build_script.sh"
```

**Second, setup your debugger.**

Using [this tutorial](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/). It may take some time and attempts to get there but it is worth it. My adb-server call script is

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/NVPACK/android-ndk-r6b/
cd $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
./ndk-gdb-eclipse --adb=/cygdrive/c/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/adb     --project=/cygdrive/c/project/path --force --verbose
```

**Third, set your logcat in verbose.**

**UPDATE: This last step can now be skipped as latest versions of Logcat output the class and line for the whole stacktrace.**

You will get long stacktraces like the one in my question. To check where the stacktrace errors point follow this [other tutorial.](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/08/tips-tricks-debugging-android-ndk-stack-traces/) My script to access the library is

```
C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r6b\toolchains\x86-4.4.3\prebuilt\windows\bin\i686-android-linux-addr2line.exe -C -f -e c:\path\to\project\libMyLib.so
```

Comment: This tutorial covers JNI perfectly well explained http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/index.html